# drupal > views > exposed filter > submit on change

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've got a view with a single exposed filter (a select). It's using ajax to re-populate when the user clicks "Apply". I'd like them not to have to click that and just re-populate when the select is changed. I'm assuming I'm going to need some JS more or less like this (though this doesn't quite seem to be working):

```
$('#edit-tid').change(function(){
  $('#views-exposed-form-MYVIEW-page-1').submit();
});
```

First, I would think that would do it, but it's not getting submitted. Anyone know why?

Second, what's the best way to inject that code? I'm thinking of using the View footer because it's easy, but any other better ideas?

UPDATE: The above code *is* working (injected via the views footer), but only the first time. I guess the select is getting overwritten by the ajax call, but the behavior isn't getting reattached (or something). Hmm...

UPDATE #2: For simplicity's sake, I'm gonna ditch the ajax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to have this code re-attached after the ajax call, it should initially be attached via Drupal.behaviors. Something like this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.myCustomModule = function(context) {
  $('#edit-tid', context).change(function(){
    $('#views-exposed-form-MYVIEW-page-1').submit();
  });
}
```

Note that the context argument is passed into the selector. Drupal.behaviors should get called again on the new content loaded via ajax.

**Update**: I didn't notice you were inserting the js via the views footer. The above should still work, just replace 'myCustomModule' with some unique identifier so you don't override other behaviors.

Comment: - can you tell me where should i write this function ?

Answer (score 6):

I think this feature works out of the box (at least in Drupal 7). Edit your view and under 
*Exposed form* choose

```
Exposed form style -> Settings
```

Then there is an option

```
Autosubmit
```

where you can choose if you want to "Automatically submit the form once an element is changed". There is also the possibility to use the option

```
Hide submit button
```

which is explained by "Hide submit button if javascript is enabled".

Answer (score 1):

@pradeep: you could insert it into a themed view template (see http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics) of your view.
(sorry, could not write this as comment according to the forum ui)

Answer (score 0):

If you need AJAX to work when changing a select option in your exposed view

```
Drupal.behaviors.myCustomModule = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-YOUR-FIELD"]', context).change(function(){
        $('#views-exposed-form-YOUR-VIEW-block-1 input.form-submit').trigger('click');
    });
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Autosubmit of Better Exposed Filters doesn't work on initial page load but it works when you change or click on options.